# Expression Engine and Solr Search

Tags: search

I am new to expression engine, but have experience working with other CMSs which have a Solr search integrated or module available (Drupal, Silverlight, TYPO3). I have searched all over but found no equivalent in expression engine.

Before I start developing one I wanted to ask the community if they know of any examples of one, code to get started, or discussion of the issue?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there are no tools that would allow Solr search integration.

You may consider one of these search tools for EE:

1. [Search](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/index.html) (included in default install)
2. [Low Search](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-search)
3. [SuperSearch](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/super-search)

There are also tools that integrate Google Search: [Low GoogleSearch](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-googlesearch) and [Google Custom Search](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/google-custom-search)